# Unable to use amazonify in Python 3. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Tags: python, pip

My code:

```
from amazonify import amazonify
from urllib.parse import urlparse

User_url = input('Enter the link here: ')
```

The error I got:

> File
> "C:\Users\jashandeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amazonify.py",
> line 4, in 
> from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: You probably shouldn't name the file `amazonify.py`.

Comment: Your error message shows a different import than that in your code example.

Comment: amazonify appears to be quite old, and was never updated beyond its initial release (2012). It's probably going to require some none trivial work to fix it. And that's if amazon even offer the same API still.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [update this import](https://github.com/rdegges/python-amazonify/blob/master/amazonify.py) to add Python 3 support:

From:

```py
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs
from urllib import urlencode
```

to:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs, urlencode
```

**Your options:**

1. Use this package with Python 2.

2. Update package source code.

Modify the import statements in `amazonify.py`.

In some cases, changing the source code can have unexpected consequences (for example, for dependent packages and scripts). In general, I do not recommend it. But it looks like this package is pretty simple and hasn't been updated for a long time.

It seems that [there will be no update](https://github.com/rdegges/python-amazonify/issues/6). You need to do everything yourself.

3. Use this as a standalone script.

This package is basically a single Python function. The author of the package did not specify a license, but you can write your own script similar to this example.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs, urlencode


def amazonify(url, affiliate_tag):
    """Generate an Amazon affiliate link given any Amazon link and affiliate
    tag.

    :param str url: The Amazon URL.
    :param str affiliate_tag: Your unique Amazon affiliate tag.
    :rtype: str or None
    :returns: An equivalent Amazon URL with the desired affiliate tag included,
        or None if the URL is invalid.
    """
    # Ensure the URL we're getting is valid:
    new_url = urlparse(url)
    if not new_url.netloc:
        return None
    # Add or replace the original affiliate tag with our affiliate tag in the
    # querystring. Leave everything else unchanged.
    query_dict = parse_qs(new_url[4])
    query_dict['tag'] = affiliate_tag
    new_url = new_url[:4] + (urlencode(query_dict, True), ) + new_url[5:]

    return urlunparse(new_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    affiliate_tag = 'tag'

    urls = [...]
    affiliate_urls = [amazonify(u, affiliate_tag) for u in urls]
    print(affiliate_urls)
```